# roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/robot_state_publisher]

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

straight dump of the error:

```
'roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/robot_state_publisher]. Please check all <node> 'name' attributes to make sure they are unique. Also check that $(anon id) use different ids. The traceback for the exception was written to the log file'
```

I am using move_base_flex for turtlebot3 navigation when I am launching the file got the error. Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error? It's really helpful for me. I tried to find [/robot_state_publisher] where this file is overwritten but I can't.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374526/roslaunch-file-contains-multiple-nodes-named-%5B/robot_state_publisher%5D/) by [Kothandaraman Kannadasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71126/kothandaraman-kannadasan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-03-23**:
Check all launch files that you start, and therein the respective node tags. The error message is pretty self-contained. if you want more help from us, you should at least tell us what launch files you are running, and whether they are from a released package or something your crafted yourself. If it is the latter, you need to share the contents of that file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, the AMCL node launched multiple times in different launch files. So, this is the reason I got the error. Now, everything works perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [Kothandaraman Kannadasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71126/kothandaraman-kannadasan/) with karma: 26 on 2021-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0